# How to make python 3 print() utf8

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, encoding, utf-8, stdout

How can I make python 3 (3.1) `print("Some text")` to stdout in UTF-8, or how to output raw bytes?

### Test.py

```python
TestText = "Test - āĀēĒčČ..šŠūŪžŽ" # this is UTF-8
TestText2 = b"Test2 - \xc4\x81\xc4\x80\xc4\x93\xc4\x92\xc4\x8d\xc4\x8c..\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa0\xc5\xab\xc5\xaa\xc5\xbe\xc5\xbd" # just bytes
print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
print(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(TestText)
print(TestText.encode("utf8"))
print(TestText.encode("cp1252","replace"))
print(TestText2)
```

Output (in CP1257 and I replaced chars to byte values `[x00]`):

```
utf-8
cp1257
Test - [xE2][xC2][xE7][C7][xE8][xC8]..[xF0][xD0][xFB][xDB][xFE][xDE]  
b'Test - \xc4\x81\xc4\x80\xc4\x93\xc4\x92\xc4\x8d\xc4\x8c..\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa0\xc5\xab\xc5\xaa\xc5\xbe\xc5\xbd'
b'Test - ??????..\x9a\x8a??\x9e\x8e'
b'Test2 - \xc4\x81\xc4\x80\xc4\x93\xc4\x92\xc4\x8d\xc4\x8c..\xc5\xa1\xc5\xa0\xc5\xab\xc5\xaa\xc5\xbe\xc5\xbd'
```

`print` is just too smart... :D There's no point using encoded text with `print` (since it always show only representation of bytes not real bytes) and it's impossible to output bytes at all, because print anyway and always encodes it in `sys.stdout.encoding`.

For example: `print(chr(255))` throws an error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Test.py", line 1, in <module>
>     print(chr(255));
>   File "H:\Python31\lib\encodings\cp1257.py", line 19, in encode
>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xff' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
> ```

By the way `print( TestText == TestText2.decode("utf8"))` returns `False`, although print output is the same.

---

How does Python 3 determine `sys.stdout.encoding` and how can I change it?

I made a `printRAW()` function which works fine (actually it encodes output to UTF-8, so really it's not raw...):

```python
 def printRAW(*Text):
     RAWOut = open(1, 'w', encoding='utf8', closefd=False)
     print(*Text, file=RAWOut)
     RAWOut.flush()
     RAWOut.close()

 printRAW("Cool", TestText)
```

Output (now it print in UTF-8):

> ```
> Cool Test - āĀēĒčČ..šŠūŪžŽ
> ```

`printRAW(chr(252))` also nicely prints `ü` (in UTF-8, `[xC3][xBC]`) and without errors :)

Now I'm looking for maybe better solution if there's any...

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39528462/5284370) out too.

Comment: TestText starts with "Test" and TestText2 starts with "Test2" so they wouldn't compare equal :D

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Clarification:

```
TestText = "Test - āĀēĒčČ..šŠūŪžŽ" # this not UTF-8...it is a Unicode string in Python 3.X.
TestText2 = TestText.encode('utf8') # this is a UTF-8-encoded byte string.
```

To send UTF-8 to stdout regardless of the console's encoding, use the its buffer interface, which accepts bytes:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(TestText2)
```

Comment: thanks :)
by the way when I said: "Test - āĀēĒčČ..šŠūŪžŽ" # this is UTF-8    
I mean that string is written in UTF-8 with IDE, py file is encoded UTF-8 and when python parses file it converts string to Python unicode...

Comment: i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: '_ReplOutput' object has no attribute 'buffer'

Comment: Python 3? We're you using an IDE?  _ReplOutput sounds like stdout was replaced with an (incorrect) file-like object.

Comment: (ok, despite struggling I can't post multiline error msg here)

Hmm...

    >>> sys.stdout.buffer().write(chr(255))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: '_io.BufferedWriter' object is not callable
    >>> sys.stdout.buffer.write(chr(252))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Python 3.2.2

Comment: @VanJone, post a new question.

Comment: @Mark, Probably I didn't make it clear enough in my last comment that the answer doesn't always work, like in my case, so posting this error message. I'm not asking any questions at all there.

Comment: @VanJone, you have errors in both statements.  `buffer` is an attribute not a function so don't call it, and `chr()` returns a Unicode string and `buffer.write` takes byte strings.

Comment: Oh my... I posted wrong error message... Of course I tried sys.stdout.buffer.write first but it failed too. The error was >>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.buffer.write(chr(252))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: And yes, it works for byte strings, so your second reason is 100% true

Answer (score 16):

This is the best I can dope out from the manual, and it's a bit of a dirty hack:

```
utf8stdout = open(1, 'w', encoding='utf-8', closefd=False) # fd 1 is stdout
print(whatever, file=utf8stdout)
```

It seems like file objects should have a method to change their encoding, but AFAICT there isn't one.

If you write to utf8stdout and then write to sys.stdout without calling utf8stdout.flush() first, or vice versa, bad things may happen.

Comment: Had issue on windows, where `cp1257` was used for printing (and failed), while I wanted `utf-8`. Following snippet worked:

`import sys;
sys.stdout = open(1, 'w', encoding='utf-8', closefd=False);
print("vadsэавфыаЭХÜÜÄ");
print(bytes("аЭХÜ", "utf-8"))`

Comment: @zwol and all: what is the rationale that the Python 3 `print` function was defined and designed not to handle Unicode?

Comment: @OldGeezer That's not correct.  It *was* defined and designed to handle Unicode.  But the interpreter thinks, for some reason that we'll probably never know, that `sys.stdout` is feeding to a terminal emulator that *doesn't* handle Unicode, only CP1257, and therefore `print` (actually `sys.stdout.write`) must convert *from* Unicode *to* CP1257 before printing, and any character not in the CP1257 repertoire can't be printed at all (unless it is escaped first, which `print` won't do for you).

Answer (score 14):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60634040)

You can manually reconfigure the encoding of stdout as of `python 3.7`

```py
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried [zwol's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597849/872616) in Python 3.6, but it didn't work for me. With some strings there was no output printed to the console.

But [iljau's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597480/how-to-make-python-3-print-utf8/68007720#comment54334824_3597849) worked: Reopen stdout with a different encoding.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(1, 'w', encoding='utf-8', closefd=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the console encoding at utf-8 with:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8', buffering=1)
```