# Python cgi encoding / special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, cgi

This prints "Test: £17" when run from the local console, but only prints "Test: " when run from the web browser. How can I rectify the issue when loaded through the browser? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print ("")

y = "£17"
print ("Test:", y)
```

Comment: what does print(y) only do?

Comment: You need to use HTML escaping - trying printing `&pound;17`

Comment: @JonClements: That's optional, the real problem is that Python `print()` encodes automatically to the terminal, but for CGI the wrong encoding is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python will encode unicode values to bytes when printing to the console.

Encode explicitly when sending to a browser, by writing directly to `sys.stdout`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.2
import sys
out = sys.stdout
out.write(b"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8\r\n")
out.write(b"\r\n")

y = "£17"
out.write("Test: {0}\r\n".format(y).encode(encoding='utf8'))
```

Note that HTTP headers should use a `\r\n` (carriage return, newline) combo, really. I've also added the encoding used to the `Content-Type` header so the browser knows how to decode it again.

For HTML, you really want to use [character entity references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) instead of Unicode code points:

```
y = "&pound;17"
out.write("Test: {0}\r\n".format(y).encode(encoding='utf8'))
```

at which point you could also just use ASCII as your encoding.

If you really, really, really want to use `print()`, then re-open `stdout` with the correct encoding:

```
utf8stdout = open(1, 'w', encoding='utf-8', closefd=False) # fd 1 is stdout

print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8", end='\r\n', file=utf8stdout)
print("", end='\r\n', file=utf8stdout)

y = "£17"
print("Test:", y, end='\r\n', file=utf8stdout)
```

You could simplify that somewhat with [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
utf8print = partial(print, end='\r\n', file=utf8stdout)
```

then use `utf8print()` without the extra keywords:

```
utf8print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8")
utf8print("")
# etc.
```

Also see the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) for details on how Python sets output encoding, as well as [this question here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597480/how-to-make-python-3-print-utf8) about printing and encoding.

Comment: Many thanks! The last option worked for the test case and for what I am working on. I wanted to use the first suggestion but it didn't seem to be working right =/ This has been a huge help, and I learned a bunch too, and is going to impact the way I do several things. Thanks again.

Comment: it seems as if there are output maximums with this method, I'm troubleshooting now. If I use utf8print too much I get a server error.

Comment: @stackity: I doubt that anything maxes out; more likely you made a different error. :-)

Comment: I came back to delete the comment (hoping that no one had responded), you're right, my shared hosting was limiting the amount of threads I could make in comparison to my localhost. My diagnosing was incorrect. Many thanks again!