# Python- writing utf-8 signed integers

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to write a file in .fits format, which as best I can tell requires utf encoding, preferably utf-8. How do I write a an integer to a file in utf-8?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unicode (utf8) reading and writing to files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

[How to encode a string in utf8 for std out:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603160/2502012)

```
myString = "string"
string.encode('utf8')
```

[A python post by Jon Skeet on how to write to a file with utf8:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/934173/2502012)

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open("lol", "w", "utf-8")
file.write(u'\ufeff')
file.close()
```