# python : unicodeEncodeError: 'charpmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026'

Tags: python, json

I try to analyse some tweets I got from tweeter, but It seems I have a probleme of encoding, if you have any idea..

```
import json

#Next we will read the data in into an array that we call tweets.
tweets_data_path = 'C:/Python34/TESTS/twitter_data.txt'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")


for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue

print(len(tweets_data))#412 tweets
print(tweet)
```

I got the mistake : 
File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
unicodeEncodeError: 'charpmap' codec can't encode character '\u2026' in position 1345: character maps to undefined

At work, I didn't get the error, but I have python 3.3, does it make a difference, do you think ?

-----EDIT

The comment from @MarkRamson answered my question

Comment: Can you provide the line where the UnicodeEncodeError happen? How did you write theses tweets? Did you encode them in UTF-8?

Comment: I will look tonight but I got the tweet from the twitter API and checked that the encoding of the file was UTF-8

Comment: The problem is that the console you're running on is not capable of handling the character you're trying to print: `…` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597480/how-to-make-python-3-print-utf8 for some hints.

Comment: This is totally that ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the encoding when opening the file:

```
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Is utf-8-sig an educated guess? ;) Then you should argue for it.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: U+2026 is the ellipsis character which makes sense in a tweet. Also, UTF-8 is the most likely encoding that any Twitter API would use. So yes, I'd say it's an educated guess... (and the -sig part is just a precaution - if there is a BOM, it handles it, if there isn't, no harm done).

Comment: Okay, half convinced. And to state the obvious, for other readers: the data is coming from a random file twitter_data.txt, so we actually can not reliably know how the data in there is encoded.

Comment: I guess the problem is rather with the `print` line than `open`.

Comment: @georg: Quite possibly, yes. `print(tweet.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode("ascii"))` might help... (instead of "ascii", you should probably use your terminal's encoding).

Comment: Actually I got an error when trying to get the content with the following lines : `tweets = pd.DataFrame()             tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['lang'], tweets_data)`. I made a print to see why I coudn't get the content and I assumed that the reason was the encoding problem encountered by the function print. I tried the same code today at work (another computer then), and I didn't get the encoding error... I wish I could understand why, but I will try your proposition tonight on my home computer and keep you updated. Thank you !