# json.dumps \u escaped unicode to utf8

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I came from this [old discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-in-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence), but the solution didn't help much as my original data was encoded differently:

My original data was already encoded in unicode, I need to output as UTF-8

```
data={"content":u"\u4f60\u597d"}
```

When I try to convert to utf:

```
json.dumps(data, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
```

the output I get is
`"content": "ä½ å¥½"` and the expected out put should be
`"content": "你好"`

I tried without `ensure_ascii=false` and the output becomes plain unescaped `"content": "\u4f60\u597d"`

How can I convert the previously \u escaped json to UTF-8?

Comment: You are reading your UTF-8 data in the wrong codec. You **have** UTF-8, but are decoding it as Latin-1 or CP1252. In other words, this is not a Python problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was unable to repreoduce this problem in the Python 3 REPL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *have* UTF-8 JSON data:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'content': u'\u4f60\u597d'}
>>> json.dumps(data, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False)
u'{\n "content": "\u4f60\u597d"\n}'
>>> json.dumps(data, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
'{\n "content": "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd"\n}'
>>> print json.dumps(data, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
{
 "content": "你好"
}
```

My terminal just *happens* to be configured to handle UTF-8, so printing the UTF-8 bytes to my terminal produced the desired output.

However, if your terminal is *not* set up for such output, it is your *terminal* that then shows 'wrong' characters:

```
>>> print json.dumps(data, indent=1,  ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8').decode('latin1')
{
 "content": "ä½ å¥½"
}
```

Note how I *decoded* the data to Latin-1 to deliberately mis-read the UTF-8 bytes.

This isn't a Python problem; this is a problem with how you are handling the UTF-8 bytes in whatever tool you used to read these bytes.

Comment: Thank you, it was my browser that's acting up. I thought the `ä½ å¥½` was encoding error on Python end. Turns out it's the output :)

Comment: @Bonk: perhaps you need to set a proper response header? `Content-Type: application/json` should be enough (as the JSON standard specifies that UTF is the default, with a BOM at the start making it possible to distinguish UTF-8 from UTF-16 and UTF-32), or include the charset explicitly with `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8`. Without a `Content-Type` header or with one set to a `text/..` mimetype the browser may well default to Latin-1.

Answer (score 4):

in python2, it works; however in python3 `print` will output like:

```
>>> b'{\n "content": "\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd"\n}'
```

do not use `encode('utf8')`:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(data, indent=1, ensure_ascii=False))
{
 "content": "你好"
}
```

or use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` instead of `print`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import json
>>> data = {'content': u'\u4f60\u597d'}
>>> sys.stdout.buffer.write(json.dumps(data, indent=1, 
ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8') + b'\n')
{
 "content": "你好"
}
```

see [Write UTF-8 to stdout, regardless of the console's encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603160)